# Sort strings by my own alphabet order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the list of strings:

```
['bsdf', 'dfgds', 'asdf']
```

I defined alphabet order:

```
'dfgsab'
```

I would like to sort my strings according to the order defined in my alphabet. So in this example the output would be:

```
['dfgds', 'asdf', 'bsdf']
```

How should I do it in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 7):

Use a combination of `sorted`, the `key=` argument and `str.index`:

```
strings = ['bsdf', 'dfgds', 'asdf']
order = 'dfgsab'
sorted(strings, key=lambda s: [order.index(c) for c in s])
```

output

```
['dfgds', 'asdf', 'bsdf']
```

Comment: Also possible to use `list.sort()` method the same way if in-place sorting is needed.